# Excel Formula "if F1>20% then G1=C"

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

What will be the formula in exel2007 for the below mentioned question:
if cell F1>20% then cell G1 will automatically give the value alphabet C

Answer (score 0):

what about put this in cell `G1`:

`IF(F1>20%,"C","")`

Note this is not a stackoverflow question and is likely moved elsewhere